# Is it correct and natural to use the verb 'belong to'?

Tags: word-choice

> They **belong to** different countries.
>
> They **belong to** rich families

In the above sentences, is it correct and natural to use the verb **'belong to'**?

Comment: Yes. 
https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=They+belong+to+rich+families&oq=They+belong+to+rich+families&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22They+belong+to%22

Comment: Here there are very nice examples: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/belong-to

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are fine.

A slightly more literary expression is to say two people "belong to different worlds," often in the context of lovers in a romantic relationship who have trouble being together:

> She was from [the wrong side of the tracks](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/wrong-other-side-of-the-tracks?q=wrong%20side%20of%20the%20tracks) and he was [born with a silver spoon](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/born-with-a-silver-spoon-in-your-mouth) -- although they belonged to different worlds nothing could keep them apart!